# running sudo with PHP

Tags: php, sudo, exec

Yes, there are many answers to a similar question, but mine is a bit more specific. I want to add the user running apache, `www-data` to sudoers, but everywhere I've read, they have added specific files access to the sudoers file. Now the problem is that there are many files that need sudo access to execute a command. I have SSH Access to the vps. How do I allow access to all PHP Files to execute any sudo command? I know this is very risky because I read so online, but how so? How can someone else execute any other code that they want? Even so, this is only going to be used by a couple of people, so there is no problem for me, in terms of security.

Comment: Sure hope those PHP files are secured properly. // Did you look at the `sudoers` documentation yet? Also the existing `sudoers` file.

Comment: I'm suspecting you are misinterpreting what you've read. Generally sudo doesn't _know_ which PHP file is invoking it.

Comment: How is PHP being called? (I can posit multiple ways  with different impact on sudo). Fir ecample  are the shell scripts which start with a line like !# /path/to/php  or are they called /path/to/php script.php or via the web server? If via a web server how is php being called - again there are different ways.

Answer (score 1):

> How can someone else execute any other code that they want?

In a perfect world, where programs don't have bugs, they can't. We don't live in a perfect world though.

Let's say you have a program `foo`. You want your PHP script to run it with `sudo` and pass user's language as an argument.

```
shell_exec('sudo foo ' . $language);
```

Now let's say a malicious actor tricks your program into setting `$language` to `'en; sudo rm -rf /'` (**do not try this yourself**). The argument to `shell_exec` becomes:

```
sudo foo en; sudo rm -rf /
```

Your server executes `sudo foo en`, then promptly begins to wipe its disk.<sup>1</sup>

This is a very basic example. There are of course possible mitigations, but there are also ways around them. You're not experienced with this, much less than potential attackers are, and they outnumber you greatly. Then there are potential bugs in the software you're using, like Apache or PHP itself. Finally, someone can exploit a completely different bug (eg. bad upload form) to plant a remote access shell and gain full access to the `www-data` account on your server. You don't want your web server to be able to run commands as root.

If you really have to do root stuff from the web server, here's what I would do:

- Don't let `www-data` use `sudo` at all.
- Create a daemon running on its own dedicated user account. Give it `sudo` access to a limited subset of commands. This daemon will execute predefined commands when signaled by the PHP process.
- Don't pass commands to the daemon as strings. Instead, hardcode commands in the daemon and give them aliases (basically make them named "functions"). The PHP process should only send the alias it wants to trigger. This prevents attackers from running arbitrary commands.
- If you have to take arguments from user input, put super-strict restrictions on it. If the input is not arbitrary (there's a known set of valid arguments), whitelist legal values. Otherwise be extremely strict with validation. In general, whitelists are safer than blacklists.

## TL;DR:

- Don't let `www-data` execute arbitrary commands as root
- Don't pass user input to shell, or at least process it strictly

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually it doesn't, because `rm` has an extra check to prevent users from destroying their system by accident, but there's a switch that lets them do that if they explicitly specify it. I'm intentionally not using it here because I don't want anybody to have a bad time. If you want to try this, do your own research. Be warned that this command is capable of bricking some motherboards.

Comment: +1 for your sentiments which are spot in, but -1 for not actually answering the question.

Comment: @davidgo Consider this a frame challenge. The question is _"How do I allow access to all PHP Files to execute any sudo command?"_, my answer is _"You don't, do this instead"_.